# gui toolkit with c++ interface and inteligent canvas support needed

Tags: c++, user-interface

I have a lot experience in tcl/tk, but I want to get rid of scripting languages for large projects. But tk canvas has a very big functionality which I have to replace with a good gui toolkit.

One of the features I need is a canvas on which I can create active graphical objects. For example, I have a circle which can be moved by mouse drag like this in tk:

```
    #!/usr/bin/wish8.5

    canvas .c
    pack .c
    set item [.c create oval 10 10 20 20] 

    .c bind $item <Any-Enter> ".c itemconfig current -fill red"
    .c bind $item <Any-Leave> ".c itemconfig current -fill blue"

    bind .c <ButtonPress-1> "setlast %x %y"
    bind .c <B1-Motion> "moveit %x %y"

    set lastx 0
    set lasty 0

    proc setlast { x y } { 
        global lastx
        global lasty
        set lastx $x
        set lasty $y
    }   

    proc moveit { x y } { 
        global lastx
        global lasty
        .c move current [expr $x-$lastx] [expr $y-$lasty]
        set lastx $x
        set lasty $y
    }
```

Any other toolkit I found needs a lot of handcrafted work for this. Typically you have to find out yourself which item on a canvas is under the mouse which is a very large amount of work for complex shapes like polygons.

Comment: Did you find an answer finally? How did you solve this? I do have exactly the same problem...

Comment: The only component I found which has a minimum functionality was the goocanvas(mm). BUT: It is not as easy to use as the tk canvas is. And you have to deal with a lot of mysterious effects coming up from unexpected behavior of the canvas widget. Calling a dialog from an mouse event on the canvas is a tragedy! And if you want to print you have to write your own printing support, as always in gtk. For me, maybe I am to stupid, it costs much much more time as expected to go with goocanvasmm. I believe using tk-canvas via c++ interface is a better way! I will split my prog to do so!gtk is not nice

Comment: Excellent idea! I consider this question answered.  I had a quick look and [link](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net) looks interesting. It uses a Tcl/Tk-isch syntax. I used Tk from Perl with the Tkx module and that uses a different syntax, but hey, it will be way easier to convert that than to remake to whole interface again in some new technology.  Anyway, keep us posted on the technical details of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried GTK+ or QT?
Well, QT mostly is a platform for development, not a GUI library, but you can try it's too.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [C++/Tk](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/) but left that path. It does not support all of Tk, eg the featured widgets such as notebook and treelist are not supported, or you cannot pass parameters to a command. Furthermore, the implementation is quite complex and if something is not working as expected it's heavy to debug. Frustrated after a week of problem solving I decided to dump C++/Tk.

Exit C++/Tk, enters [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) (you should say "cute", but it's a bit silly, so I say "queue tee"). It has a commercial but also an open source license, there is active development going on, it is well documented with plenty of examples, it supports most desktop and mobile OSes, there is an active community with wiki and blogs, ... Besides the GUI and graphics stuff there are other modules available for multimedia, networks, SQL, testing, ...

As the development of QT started way back in 1991 (and it was part of Nokia for some time), there are some parts that are "old" and replaced by new stuff, but in contrast to Microsoft the documentation is much clearer on this. And also in contrast to Microsoft, the whole set of technologies is coherent.

For the integration with C++ there are two ways:

1. Use MSVS and the QT add-in. I tried that but couldn't make it work as it should. Maybe I should have tried more, but after two days trying I had enough of it.
2. Use the QT IDE that will use the C++ compiler you have installed. This works fine and that's the way I am doing it now. A disadvantage is that the edit time error checking is not that strong as in MSVS. An advantage however is that when you have the free version of MSVS you are able to compile for 64 bit too.

If you want to make a GUI you should definitely consider Qt.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But especially an intelligent canvas widget is not available in Qt so I decided to not move to Qt. And my experience with Qt was, that it is very consistent in the interface design. I dislike all the macro stuff there. Maybe newer versions are a bit more consistent and maybe use all the C++11 stuff. But as mentioned, there is no canvas...

Comment: Well there is a canvas in Qt, it is called `QGraphicsScene`. You build with that a scene with all the graphical objects and then show it with `QGraphicsView`. Building and viewing is separated so that you can have more than one view for a scene.